# How to exclude server-side modules (like Express) from client build of Next.js app?

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js

I added this code to `next.config.js` to exclude troublish node modules from client build:

```
if (!isServer) {
config.node = {
fs : 'empty',
net :'empty',
express: 'empty'
}
}
```

And I then I got error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`. With configuration above only NodeJS native libraries (like "fs" and "net") are excluded from client build but not external ones (like Express). So how can I exclude Express (which depends on 'fs' and 'net' modules)?

Source of this issue: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9976

UPD: I also tried to set webpack config external to `nodeExternals()` on client build (when `isServer` is false). But in browser console I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/interopRequireDefault (interopRequireDefault":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:792)
    at fn (bootstrap:150)
    at Object.<anonymous> (next-dev.js:1)
    at Object../node_modules/next/dist/client/next-dev.js (next-dev.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:792)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.js?ts=1578410502794:1
```